# iOS unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x45e8

Tags: objective-c, ios, unrecognized-selector

Below is my code that attempt to encrypt the data

input/invoke my encryption method:

```
[self myED:@"wcc123" :@"hahaha" :@"yyyy"];

- (NSData*) myED:(NSData*)data :(NSData*) key :(NSData*)iv{

    @try {
        // Try something
        NSLog( @"Original String: %@", data );


        size_t bufferSize = [data length]*2;
        void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);
        size_t encryptedSize = 0;    
        CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,                                          
                                              [key bytes], [key length], [iv bytes], [data bytes], [data length],                                          
                                              buffer, bufferSize, &encryptedSize);  
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e); 
    }
    @finally {
        // Added to show finally works as well
    }


    return nil;

}
```

However, when try to run this code and it prompt me exception below

> 2012-07-03 16:52:44.776 wccTest[930:f803] Exception:
>   -[__NSCFConstantString bytes]:

Can anyone help/advice on this?

Answer (score 2):

Your method expects `NSData`, and you are passing `NSString`s.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
[self myED:@"wcc123" :@"hahaha" :@"yyyy"];
```

Try calling

```
[self myED:[@"wcc123" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] :[@"hahaha" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] :[@"yyyy" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: And please give names to your parameters if you don't want any developer you work with to scream at you.

Answer (score 0):

Following @borrrden comment I will also give a self-explicative name to your method. For example:

```
- (NSData*)encryptEDData:(NSData*)data withKey:(NSData*)key initVector:(NSData*)iv {
    // same as before
}
```

So, the `selector` for this method will be `encryptEDData:withKey:initVector:`.

You can call that method like:

```
NSData* edData = //...
NSData* keyData = //...
NSData* ivData = //...
[self encryptEDData:edData withKey:keyData initVector:ivData];
```

Furthermore, I would perform the `NSString` to `NSData` conversion within the method leaving it to accept strings. I think it allows to understand better the goal for that method.

Hope that helps.